# How to Lazy loading images using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying not to load images that are not inside the view port .

Here is what I did

```
$.fn.is_on_screen = function () {
    var win = $(window);
    var viewport = {
        top: win.scrollTop(),
        left: win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
};
CheckIt();

function CheckIt() {
    $('.target').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('img').attr('data-src')) { // if target element exists in DOM
            if ($(this).is_on_screen()) { // if target element is visible on screen after DOM loaded
                if ($(this).find('img').attr('data-src')) {
                    var source = $('.target').find('img').attr('data-src');

                    $('.target').find('img').attr('src', source);
                    $(this).find('.log').html('<div class="alert alert-success">target element is visible on screen</div>');

                }
                // log info     
            } else {

                $(this).find('.log').html('<div class="alert">target element is not visible on screen</div>'); // log info
            }
        }
    });

}
$(window).scroll(function () { // bind window scroll event
    CheckIt();
});
```

And the **JSFIDDLE** for the problem is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/p8paydcd/7/)

But unfortunately the images that are outside the viewport are also loading .

Can any one let me know where I am going wrong in this

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: @artm check in the console for the list that are outside of the viewport you will find they are also having the attribute `src` cording to the logic only the images that are in viewport should have src tag

Comment: I'm looking at the fiddle you've sent, right after run I check the html and only the first 4 have src attoribute, the rest don't.

Comment: @artm Oh! I was checking and rechecking too many time I guess I mixed it up with some other fiddles that i created for the same thing. I checked just now and yes it works .

Comment: @artm so is there a way i can close this question ?

Comment: I think the only way to "close" a question is by accepting a valid answer.

Comment: @artm oh wait there is a mistake in my code actually I forgot to comment it if you see the code I pasted and the fiddle there is little difference . I observed now . Since I am writing `$(this).find('img').removeAttr('src');`  in the else part thats why its not showing src tag in the elments that are outside the viewport

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61677/discussion-between-vikram-and-artm).